# Why isn't my shutdownhook in my main method being called?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have the following in my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = getConfig();
    Jedis jedis = configure(properties)

    jedis.subscribe(queueHandler, "queue");

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.debug("SHUTTING DOWN");
            jedis.close();
        }
    });
}
```

I noticed that the code inside my shutdown hook is never run, why is that? How do I clean up resources that my main method has a hold of?

Comment: How do you check if your shutdown hook has been run? If logger is closed in another shutdown hook before yours, it probably won't be able to log your message.

Comment: I think that you need a System.exit in your code for the shutdown hook to be executed.

Answer (score 2):

"Note that subscribe is a blocking operation ..." (from [the AdvancedUsage wiki](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage)).

This in turn means that the shutdown-hook is only registered after you unsubscribe or shutdown Jedis,
and you probably only reach that part of the code when the JVM is already shutting down 
(in which case the newly added shutdown hook is ignored: shutdown hooks have to be registered before the JVM shuts down).

"For more usage examples check the tests." (from the [main Github page](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis))

So let's look at the [PublishSubscribeCommandsTest](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/tests/commands/PublishSubscribeCommandsTest.java#L33).

The test is just one subscribe operation but within the subscribe operation, the `JedisPubSub` un-subscribes itself when it receives a specific message thereby unblocking itself so that the test can finish.

Two things you can experiment with:

- register the shutdown hook before calling `jedis.subscribe`
- copy the code from the test and modify it so you can experiment with blocking and unblocking threads and shutting down Jedis from within a shutdown hook (to clean up used resources)

Answer (score 0):

The shutdown hook will invoke if the jvm shuts down. Make sure that the program exits. If the jedis is running in the background (in a thread) even if the last statement is executed then the shutdown hook will not invoke. In such case, you have to stop that thread. The best way will be to try `jedis.shutdown();` (after adding shutdown hook, here as the last statement) to shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

Regular exit of Main-Method differs a little from explicit calling `System.exit(0);`

so, try following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //all your code...
    System.exit(0); //NOTE: non zero status will work different!
}
```